# Avoiding property ambiguity in external code

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

I am using an external library (that I cannot change), and am seeing an ambiguous reference when I try to set a property.

Here's a sample (not the actual library or property names)

External code:

```
namespace ExternalLibrary1.Area1
{
    public interface Interface0: Interface1, Interface2
    {

    }

    public interface Interface1
    {
        double Item { get; set; }
    }

    public interface Interface2
    {
        double Item { get; set; }
    }

    public class Class0 : Interface0
    {
        double Item;
    }
}
```

My code:

```
Interface0 myObject = new Class1();
myObject.Item = 2.0;
//above line gives me compile error "Ambiguity between 'ExternalLibrary1.Area1.Interface1.Item' and 'ExternalLibrary1.Area1.Interface2.Item'
```

As seen in my code, I get an ambiguity error trying to assign to the `Item` property.

I cannot change this library. I know I would like to assign the value to `Interface1`. Is there any way I can explicitly specify this to prevent the compile error?

Comment: This is a terrible design decision in my opinion

Comment: Pick an interface, any interface, just not Interface0.

Comment: @HansPassant I should have mentioned I have to work with `Interface0` for the other properties it has, but I've made it work by casting to `Interface1` for assigning those properties only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems like an odd decision on the part of whoever designed the `Interface0`, `Interface1`, `Interface2` type hierarchy. What you can do is to cast to (or assign to a reference of) the interface type for which you want to set the property:

```
Interface1 myObject = new Class1();
myObject.Item = 2.0;
```

Comment: The actual code is significantly more complex (there are actually a dozen different interfaces involved) - I understand why the interfaces were created that way, even if it could have been done differently. At any rate, your answer worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As an aside to Asad's answer, you can also cast it at the time of assignment, in the event that you need to use other properties and methods on `Interface0`.

```
Interface0 myObject = new Class1();
(myObject as Interface1).Item = 2.0;
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I've ended up doing, as `Interface0` is the primary one I need to work with.